# Move data from ES 2.4 to ES 5

Tags: java, elasticsearch

What is the best and fastest method to move all of my ES data of the 2.4 cluster and on to a new 5.0 cluster? (725 million documents)

I've written a small java Transport client that uses the scroll api to fetch all the documents from the 2.4 one and then I use http PUT (via apache httpclient library) to index them into the new cluster. This will take a *very* long time. Is there a better/faster way?

Comment: This could be [helpful](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-upgrade.html) before you make the movement.

Comment: I was not aware that ES 5.0 could import ES 2.4 snapshots. Thank you!